# Stack behavior on function call during a format string exploit

Tags: information-gathering, format-string

I have some issues trying to resolve a war game with a format string vulnerability.
So here is the code of the program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    char text[1024];
    if(argc!=2)
    {
        printf("Usage : %s <texte>\n",argv[0]);
        exit(0);
    }
    strncpy(text,argv[1],1023);
    printf("Voici votre texte :\n");
    printf(text);
    printf("\n");
    exit(0);
}
```

So you can see the code disassembled and I assume that the call at `0x80484fb` is the call to the vulnerable function.

[image: gdb analysis]

First, I don't understand why there are already those values from `0xbffff834` to `0xbffff84c` on the stack. Indeed, the value on the top of the stack (added in `0x80484f8` in the main thread) seems to be the argument passed to the `printf` function but I don't know what are those other values passed before.

The second thing I don't understand is why does the result not show the address `0xbffff840` and start printing `0xbffffe1b`. I though that the `%x` would print the first value of the stack and then the second and carry on like this.

Comment: Please don't post code in pictures; it is hard to read (or impossible, for some). Instead, copy paste the code into the question.

Comment: @Anders Honestly, I think this is a case where it is fine to post a picture. The output is colored and specially formatted due to being from a debugger.

Comment: @forest Granted, this is 100x better than just a lazy screenshot with lots of irrelevant junk around it. Still not a fan, but I see your point.